# How to use a button to delete it's container parent in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, widget, kivymd

Hi I am dynamically adding widgets in python to a BoxLayout created in kv. Those widgets contain some labels, textfiedls and buttons. I want to use one of those buttons to delete it's parent container from the Boxlayout.
The Boxlayout has a button that creates a dialog which I use to dynamically add widgets to the BoxLayout.
I have no idea how to go about this, please help.
The dynamically added widgets look like this

```
<Module>
orientation: "horizontal"
valign: "top"
size_hint_y: None
height: "50dp"
MDLabel:
    id: module_name_label
    size_hint_x: .3
    text: ""
MDTextField:
    id: module_total
    size_hint_x: .2
    hint_text: "Total"
    text: "0"
MDTextField:
    id: module_input_nr
    size_hint_x: .2
    text: "1"
MDIconButton:
    id: module_plus_btn
    size_hint_x: .1
    icon: "plus-box"
MDIconButton:
    id: module_minus_btn
    size_hint_x: .1
    icon: "minus-box"
MDIconButton:
    id: module_del_button 
    size_hint_x: .1
    icon: "delete"
```

They get added in python by means of a dialog box with a button whose on_release is binded to the following function:

- dialog box:

  ```
    def show_confirmation_dialog(self):
           if not self.dialog:
               self.dialog = MDDialog(
                   title="Modul:",
                   type="custom",
                   content_cls=Content(),
                   buttons=[
                       MDFlatButton(
                           text="CANCEL",
                           theme_text_color="Custom",
                           text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                           on_release=self.cancel_dialog,
                       ),
                       MDFlatButton(
                           text="Add",
                           theme_text_color="Custom",
                           text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                           on_release = self.add_dialog
                       ),
                   ],
               )
           self.dialog.open()
  ```
- Function binded to the button on the dialog box

  ```
        def add_dialog(self, obj):
            module_name = self.dialog.content_cls.ids.module_input.text
            temp_module = Module()
            temp_module.ids.module_name_label.text=module_name
            self.module_list.update({module_name:0})
            self.root.ids.module_screen.add_widget(temp_module)
            self.dialog.dismiss(force=True)
            self.dialog = None
            pass
  ```

I will be grateful for any help or for any pointers on what documentation I need to read to learn how to go about this. Thanks

Comment: Try something like `self.parent.parent.remove_widget(self.parent)` in the `on_release` of the delete Button.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JohnAnderson. It makes sense, I should've thought to go through the parent of it's parent.